# Merge two (or more) identical dictionaries having just one value in common - in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two (but it could be three or more) dictionaries like this

```
>>> d1
{'address': '', 'cf': 'DRSSFN88A26A459E', 'first_name': 'Stefano', 'last_name': ''}
>>> d2
{'address': 'Via Due Giugno, 25', 'cf': 'DRSSFN88A26A459E', 'first_name': '', 'last_name': ''}
>>> d3
{'address': '', 'cf': 'DRSSFN88A26A459E', 'first_name': '', 'last_name': 'Lauzi'}
```

So, the only value in common is cf. I'd like to merge all of these into one that gathers all of the values from every dict, like

```
>>> d3
{'address': 'Via Due Giugno, 25', 'cf': 'DRSSFN88A26A459E', 'first_name': 'Stefano', 'last_name': 'Lauzi'}
```

How could I do that?

EDIT:

I've tried this (with just two dicts), but the result is not the expected

```
>>> def merge_two_dicts(d1, d2):
...     d = d1.copy()
...     d.update(d2)
...     return d
```

Comment: What have you tried? I'm not going to just write the code for you, please post your attempt.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: _I've tried this (with just two dicts), but the result is not the expected_ What did you expect, and how did the results differ from that?

Comment: Just as Tadhg McDonald-Jensen wrote, I had every key updated (with the empty value). Anyway Burhan Khalid's answer is the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> d = {i:v for q in [d1,d2,d3] for i,v in q.iteritems() if v != ''}
>>> d
{'first_name': 'Stefano', 'last_name': 'Lauzi', 'cf': 'DRSSFN88A26A459E', 'address': 'Via Due Giugno, 25'}
```

Of course, this won't work if you have different/unique `cf` values, for that you'll have to put another conditional in there - and I leave that up to you.

Answer (score 1):

`dict.update` updates every key, even if the value was empty.

```
>>> d = {'a':'hi'}
>>> d.update({'a':'', 'b':'hello'})
>>> d
{'a': '', 'b': 'hello'}
```

you could easily discriminate against empty values with comprehension:

```
def merge_two_dicts(first, other):
    final = first.copy()
    final.update((k,v) for k,v in other.items() if v)
    return final
```

Then to generalize this for any number you could just take a variable amount of others:

```
def merge_dicts(first,*others):
    final = first.copy()
    for d in others:
        final.update((k,v) for k,v in d.items() if v)
    return final

>>> merge_dicts(d1,d2,d3)
{'cf': 'DRSSFN88A26A459E', 'address': 'Via Due Giugno, 25', 'last_name': 'Lauzi', 'first_name': 'Stefano'}
```